# how to make gdb show line numbers with respect to function's head?

Tags: c, gdb

[image: this] this is my gdb output. How can I make it write the line numbers, instead of `...227` to be `main+1`, as it shows when I disassemble it?

Comment: Is that not exactly what it's saying in the angle brackets?

Comment: yeah... I want it to show when I'm stepping into the code after the BP so it would be easier for me to follow

Comment: Oh, right, totally misread that. Carry on :)

Comment: The disassembly is showing _relative address_ not  _relative kine number_.  There is no direct correspondence between address and source file line number.  It is difficult therefore to understand what you want or how it will help.

Comment: @Clifford what I want is to see the same enumeration I see in the diisassembly stage (e.g. `0x0000... <+0>`) and the stepping into stage (e.g. only `0x000...`)... I'm not looking for the a relation to the source file, but to the location in memory (i.e. seeing near each command I step onto, the corresponding `<+N>` from the disassembly)

Comment: I think then `display /i $pc` is what you need - I have added to my answer.  You should however clarify your requirements by editing the question rather then in a comment.  That said your comment is still less than clear.  I think the issue is that you are asking for line numbers to be printed in a different format, when in fact it is not the line numbers but the address that you actually want.

Comment: Indeed. Your last statement is what I'm looking for. Ill edit my question later, when I'll be near my laptop

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear exactly what you are asking since machine instruction address and source-code line number are not directly related.  Possibly suited to your need is to use *mixed* source/disassembly.  For example:

```
(gdb) disassemble /m main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
5       {
   0x08048330 <+0>:    push   %ebp
   0x08048331 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048333 <+3>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x08048336 <+6>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048339 <+9>:    sub    $0x10,%esp

6         printf ("Hello.\n");
   0x0804833c <+12>:   movl   $0x8048440,(%esp)
   0x08048343 <+19>:   call   0x8048284 <puts@plt>

7         return 0;
8       }
   0x08048348 <+24>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0804834d <+29>:   leave
   0x0804834e <+30>:   ret

End of assembler dump.
```

This shows each line of source code ahead of the machine code disassembly associates with it.  Both the source line numbers and instruction addresses and offsets are shown.  Note that it is likely to be far less comprehensible if you apply optimisation as often code is eliminated or re-ordered such that it no longer has a direct correspondence to the source code order.

If rather you want to show the current program counter address/offset as you step, then that can be done with the `display /i $pc` command:

```
(gdb) display /i $pc
(gdb) run                                                                                         
Starting program: /home/a.out                                                                     

Breakpoint 2, main () at main.c:13                                                                
13          printf("Hello World");                                                                
1: x/i $pc                                                                                        
=> 0x40053a <main+4>:   mov    $0x4005d4,%edi                                                     
(gdb) step                                                                                        
__printf (format=0x4005d4 "Hello World") at printf.c:28                                           
28      printf.c: No such file or directory.                                                      
1: x/i $pc                                                                                        
=> 0x7ffff7a686b0 <__printf>:   sub    $0xd8,%rsp                                                 
(gdb)
```